# error checking to ensure that a field isn't blank?

Tags: php, validation, error-checking

My website has an opt-in member directory. Currently, the error checking function simply looks at the form $_POST to see `if (!empty($userRealName))` and then allows the member to appear in the list.

It took about 30 minutes for someone to show up as a blank name in the list, and upon examination of the database I've determined it's because their "real name" is    - in other words, a single space.

So, clearly that blows right through my simple `!empty()` check. Where do I go from here to enforce users needing a name to be listed in the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [trim](http://php.net/trim) to remove blank characters in the beginning and end of the string. Also try to enforce which characters are allowed in the field, for example with [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) or [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var).